# CollectionViewCell Image does not fit in the cell while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, collectionview

[image: Click to view the image]

Hi Everyone,

I am having a collectionView of images. While scrolling horizontally, the images don't fit in the cell. I am running it in the iPhone 11 pro max and the width is 414.

I have enabled the paging. I have tried, aspect fit, fill. It doesn't help much.  I want to fit the images to the cell while scrolling

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewController:UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    let cellIdentifier = "SecondImageCell"
    var images: [String] = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"]
    var indexpath = NSString()
    var startIndex = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()
    indexpath = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "indexPath") as! NSString
     self.paging_ref.numberOfPages = images.count

    }


    @IBOutlet weak var paging_ref: UIPageControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
         let str = "\(indexpath)" // here i'm converting indexpath which is NSString into String
         startIndex = Int(str)!
        // here i'm converting str into integer value
        startIndex -= 1
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: startIndex, section: 0)
        self.secondCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        self.secondCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
        print(indexPath)
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return images.count
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
     cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.imageView2.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
     return cell

 }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
           let pageIndex = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
           self.paging_ref.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)
       }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's either your constraints are off or your content mode isn't **aspectFit**

```
SecondCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
...
// 1. make sure your image is constrained fully
// 2. imageView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
...
}
```

Comment: Error : the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values, minus the content insets top and bottom values.

Comment: Okay, maybe you should post your SecondCollectionViewCell.swift as well and look at **sizeForItemAt:** https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview

Comment: ok I got the solution. I just removed the minimum spacing from 10 to 0. Thanks.